# VL53L0X error: "API Status -20: Control Interface Error"

Tags: i2c

I had a working prototype which detects distance. Plugged it in yesterday and it keeps giving me an error:

API Status -20: Control Interface Error.

I checked up i2cdetect and I'm getting the output:
[image: i2cdetect output]

The i2c item I am trying to get should appear at 0x29 (0x1b and 0x5a are different modules, namely temp sensor and DLP projector respectively) but as you can see, it's not visible anymore. Any suggestions on what might be the problem?

I'm not very sure of how this works, but due to lock-down its currently not possible for me to contact the guy who made the prototype originally.

The prototype uses beaglebone black.

Comment: It's generally better to type text out instead of posting an image of it.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with you, but the output here has a format which is best preserved. Besides, nothing to copy paste from it.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the post on GITHUB for this sensor [here](https://github.com/cassou/VL53L0X_rasp/issues/5), it looks like you have duff data in the sensors register.

The proposed solution is to remove all power from the sensor to reset it.  Without knowing more about your board I cannot say how to fully do this but unplugging the Pi and any battery backup would be a good place to start :)

Other thoughts I had with this being I2C is that you have two devices at the same address or you have lost the pull up resistance for some reason. Try one device at a time.

Comment: The post mentioned (in 1st comment) states and I quote "Using i2cdetect still brings up 0x29 as expected." Which refers to i2cdetect showing 0x29 which for isn't happening.
I've since disconnected my beaglebone from main power and restarted the whole device. I gave it some time before restarting (about an hour just in case). I can't remove the devices one by one as the are pretty much soldered in. Any way I can do it via code?

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see your comment anywhere.  I’ve never used a Beaglebone board so you may do better flagging this as that board and not just i2c. if You could edit the question with the accurate status it would help everyone reading the post.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity, I meant the 1st comment in the link you provided. I also can't tag it as beaglebone as the tag doesn't exist yet (and I lack the rep to be able to create it).

Comment: I've added the tag for you - as I do not know the board or computer I'm a bit stuck. Hope you find a solution